# save an image which reside on client device to the database on server

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, image

I want to perform a simple using ASP.NET. I want the user to select as many images as he wants and save these images to the database which runs on the server. Each time the user wants to add a new image he clicks on "Add" to add a new image. The image has accompanying properties such as the location and time where it was taken. The location is input through an Text Box and the date through a Date Picker.

The problem is in saving the image to the server.

Is there any control to carry out this task?

I have tried using the Upload control and the Devexpress ASPxUpload control but to no avail. The upload control also requires me to upload the image first to the server before saving it to the database.

I have tried to implement the control which represents the image and its date and location as user control but whenever  I click on the upload button the event is not called

Here is the code for the user control

```
    public partial class ucVerificationItem : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    public byte[] data { set; get; }
    public byte[] Photo { get { return data; } }
    //ASPxFormLayout1_E3.Text is a Text Box which has the verification text
    public string Verify { get { return ASPxFormLayout1_E3.Text; } }
    //ASPxFormLayout1_E4.Text is a Text Box which has the caption text
    public string Caption { get { return ASPxFormLayout1_E4.Text; } }
    //ASPxFormLayout1_E5.Date is a DateEdit which has the date
    public DateTime Date { get { return ASPxFormLayout1_E5.Date; } }

    // to expose the button to the page from which it is gonna be called
    public ASPxButton Button { get { return ASPxButton1; } }
    //to expose the uplaod control
    public ASPxUploadControl UploadControl { get { return ASPxFormLayout1_E2; } }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void ASPxButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ASPxFormLayout1_E2.UploadedFiles[0].SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~\\temp\\"+ASPxFormLayout1_E2.UploadedFiles[0].FileName));
    }

    protected void ASPxFormLayout1_E2_FileUploadComplete(object sender, DevExpress.Web.ASPxUploadControl.FileUploadCompleteEventArgs e)
    {
        ASPxFormLayout1_E2.UploadedFiles[0].PostedFile.InputStream.Read(data, 0, ASPxFormLayout1_E2.PostedFile.ContentLength);
    }
}
```

Here is the code of the page from which the control is called

```
        protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        if (IsPostBack)
        {
            if (Session["Photos"] == null)
            {
                List<ucVerificationItem> list = new List<ucVerificationItem>();
                Session["Photos"] = list;
            }
            foreach (ucVerificationItem item in Session["Photos"] as List<ucVerificationItem>)
            {
                PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(item);
            }
        }       
    }

        protected void addPhotoASPxButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ucVerificationItem item = (ucVerificationItem)Page.LoadControl("~/Company/Forms/ucVerificationItem.ascx");
        (Session["Photos"] as List<ucVerificationItem>).Add(item);
        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(item);
    }
```

Hope this is clear enough

Answer (score 1):

> The location is input through an Text Box

No. THe server can not access the location, especially if it is coded as local path from the client (i.e. C:\blablabla)

Use a FIleUploadControl and send the binary data as part of the request to the server.

Besides there being a number of approaches to make it nice with jquery etc., bsi file upload is core part of HTML and you should have learned about it when you read some HTML documentation.

http://webdesign.about.com/od/htmltags/p/input-file-tag.htm

talks about it.

The core syntax is:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" accept="image/jpg,image/gif">
</form>
```

- You MUST have enctype as multipart, otherwise the binary data can not be sent, and it must be a POST - no GET requests.
- Input type=file is how the browser knows that it should post the fike.

On top of that you can do a lot of jquery (or get scripts for that on the internet) that allow drag and drop and other VERY nice things - like dropping multiple files and uploading them one by one as separate requests, with visual feedback.

Comment: I meant the location where the picture was taken. It is input by the user through a text box. I understands that the server cannot access the location due to security restrictions